# Combining records in sequential order

Tags: sql

I have a data source that contains user log ins and log outs as individual records.  I need to find a way to get the total log in time based on each log in session, so I need to combine the log in and log out into one record each to find the time interval between them and then sum up the intervals to find the total log in time.

The data source does not have session ids so I can't join the records that way.

[image: My data looks like this.]

[image: I want it to look like this.]

Anyone know of an easy way to do this?

Comment: How is it at all possible that you can tell with any level of certainty that a user didn't log in at 9:00am today, and log out at 12:00pm the same day, or the next day, or `N` days later?

Comment: Please tag with the database you are really using.

Comment: If a user has login time 9:00 and logout time 9:00, how do you know if the user came for 30 seconds, or left for 30 seconds?

Comment: `JSmith` is a unique identifier so it should *only be stored in the database once!* Create a `user_accounts` table with a `user_name` column and then `INNER JOIN` the two tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the login/logout records are perfectly aligned, then `lead()` is quite convenient:

```
select user, login_time, logout_time
from (select user, state, time as login_time,
             lead(time) over (partition by user order by time) as logout_time
      from t
      where state in ('login', 'logout')
     ) t
where state = 'login';
```

If the data actually has anomalies, then ask a *new* question.  provide sample data, desired results, a clear explanation of how to deal with missing or multiple states in a row, and an appropriate database tag.

Comment: The table has records for other states in between, but I can write a subquery to pull just logins and logouts and apply that logic above, right?

Comment: @RobOng . . . Just filter on the two states you care about.  I updated the answer.